# Can the App Store be installed on Xcode's iOS Simulator on the new ARM/M1 powered Macs?

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode-simulator, apple-silicon

Years ago on Stack Overflow people already [asked about installing the App Store on the iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611146/can-i-install-the-app-store-in-an-ios-simulator) but the answer was you couldn't because the Simulator doesn't run ARM code but Intel code.

> The Simulator does not run **ARM** code, ONLY **x86** code. Unless you have
> the raw source code from Apple, you won't see the App Store on the
> Simulator.

So you can only run apps you're working on and compiling yourself, and the few that are preinstalled on the Simulator.

But as of very recently Macs now also run on ARM. So can the iOS Simulator on an M1 powered Mac have the App Store installed on it now?

Comment: I am wondering too, is it possible technically to copy some App from iOS device (Jailbroken I guess) to the iOS Simulator container after resigning with codesign&xcrun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The iOS Simulator does not have an App Store.

There are many iOS Apps available in the macOS App Store on Apple Silicon Macs.